# Call of Duty on PS3, local play and ranking?

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-series

We're looking into creating a small gaming club at work where we meet and play Call of Duty on PS3 using "LAN Play" so that it's only us at work that will play together.

The question is, will we be able to create local characters that will get XP, ranks, unlocks, etc.? Or will we have to play some kind of online play to get those things?

We don't care if the characters are locked to local play, if that is even possible, since this is just local play fun.

So, is this possible? If this is possible in one of the CoD games on PS3 I would like to know which one, but I suspect this borders on asking for recommendations.

Comment: I don't really have time to write an acceptable answer, but I'm pretty sure that LAN play with locally created player profiles is possible in CoD 4 Modern Warfare and all newer CoDs.

Comment: I figure it is possible to play, I'm specifically wondering if we can rank and get unlocks so that we can level up our LAN players.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen i don't think you can the only way to play over lan is through private match on PS3 and you don't rank in private match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following Call of Duty's support LAN-play on the PS3:

- Call of Duty 4: Modern Warfare
- Call of Duty 5: World at War
- Call of Duty 6: Modern Warfare 2
- Call of Duty 7: Black Ops
- Call of Duty 8: Modern Warfare 3
- Call of Duty 9: Black Ops 2
- Call of Duty 10: Ghosts

Situation for MW2: (I'm not quite sure but I think the concept is the same for all)

Each Playstation profile has **one** save for LAN-play+splitscreen-play (an offline save) and **a seperate** one for online-play.

All progress you make on LAN will be saved to your LAN-play+splitscreen-play save.
All progress you make online will be saved to your online-play save.

It is not possible to use your offline save for online games.

Comment: This sounds very promising. That important part (that is, the nice part, not important in the sense that if it weren't true we wouldn't play) is that we can earn unlocks per player so that we have something to work against.

Comment: this is pretty much how I remember it, I currently don't have the option to build up a LAN setup and try it myself, but I remember trying to modify gamesaves to troll my friends, and that, of course cant have been online gamesaves.